# Encoding Issue with HttpUrlConnection in Android

Tags: android, encoding, httpclient, httpurlconnection

I want to send an XML message to a server from my Android Mobile app via HTTP post.

I tried it with HttpUrlConnection, following these steps:

```
URL url = new URL(vURL);

HttpUrlConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);

// Adding headers (code removed)

conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-16");
OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

// Adding XML message to the connection output stream 
// I have removed exception handling to improve readability for posting it here
out.write(pReq.getBytes()); // here pReq is the XML message in String
out.close();

conn.connect();
```

Once I get the response, the stream reading part is in done this manner:

```
BufferedReader in = null;
StringBuffer sb;
String result = null;

    try {

        InputStreamReader   isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            // Just in case, I've also tried:
            // new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-16");
            // new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-16LE");
            // new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-16BE");
            // new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");

        in = new BufferedReader(isr);

        sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";

        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
            sb.append(line);

        in.close();

        result = sb.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Now the result string I get is in some unreadable format/encoding.**

When I try the same thing with HttpClient it works correctly. Here is the streaming reading part once I get an HttpResponse after the HttpClient.execute call:

```
BufferedReader in = null;
    InputStream         is;
    StringBuffer sb;
    String decompbuff = null;

    try {

        is = pResponse.getEntity().getContent();
        InputStreamReader   isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        in = new BufferedReader(isr);

        // Prepare the String buffer
        sb = new StringBuffer("");

        String line = "";

        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
            sb.append(line);

        in.close();

         // gZip decompression of response. Note: message was compressed before
         // posting it via HttpClient (Posting code is not mentioned here)
        decompbuff = Decompress(sb.toString());

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return decompbuff;
```

Some help is appreciated in understanding the problem.

Comment: Can you show us your `writestream (out);` implementation? Are you closing the stream? Do you really have UTF16? Little or Big-Endian? With/without BOM? How does the response look like? Can you show us the code which works with HttpClient?

Comment: In response to your questions:
I am closing the stream after writing to it. I will post the code which works with HttpClient in a few minutes. The response that I get in the "result" string looks like 'chinese characters' :).   I didn't understand what you mean by - "Do you really have UTF 16 ..."

Answer (score 1):

One (severe) problem could be that you're ignoring the encoding of input and output.

**Input**

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-16");
OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

// Adding XML message to the connection output stream 
// I have removed exception handling to improve readability for posting it here
out.write(pReq.getBytes()); // <-- you use standard platform encoding
out.close();
```

better:

```
out.write(pReq.getBytes("UTF-16"));
```

**Output**

You probably ignored compression, which would better look like this (taken from [DavidWebb](https://github.com/hgoebl/DavidWebb/blob/master/src/main/java/com/goebl/david/WebbUtils.java)):

```
static InputStream wrapStream(String contentEncoding, InputStream inputStream) 
        throws IOException {
    if (contentEncoding == null || "identity".equalsIgnoreCase(contentEncoding)) {
        return inputStream;
    }
    if ("gzip".equalsIgnoreCase(contentEncoding)) {
        return new GZIPInputStream(inputStream);
    }
    if ("deflate".equalsIgnoreCase(contentEncoding)) {
        return new InflaterInputStream(inputStream, new Inflater(false), 512);
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("unsupported content-encoding: " + contentEncoding);
}

// ...

    InputStream is = wrapStream(conn.getContentEncoding(), is);
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-16");

    in = new BufferedReader(isr);

    sb = new StringBuffer("");
    String line = "";

    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
        sb.append(line); // <-- you're swallowing linefeeds!

    in.close();
    result = sb.toString();
```

It would be better to let the XML-Parser consume your InputStream directly. Don't create a JAVA string, but let the parser scan the bytes. It will automatically detect the encoding of the XML.

Generally there might be still an issue, because we don't know what type of UTF-16 you use. Can be BigEndian or LittleEndian. That's why I asked, if you really need UTF-16. If you don't have to treat with some asian languages, UTF-8 should be more efficient and easier to use.

So the "solution" I gave you is not guaranteed to work - you have to fiddle with UTF-16 BE/LE a bit and I wish you good luck and patience.

Another remark: in your example above you first construct the String and then `Decompress` it. That is the wrong order. The stream comes compressed (gzip, deflate) and must be decompressed first. Then you get the String.